# Haskell: How to make foldr/build fusion happen in (zip [0..])?

Tags: list, haskell, ghc

In Haskell, we can use this useful idiom to get from a list that of indexed elements in it:

```
indexify :: (Num i) => [a] -> [(i,a)]
indexify = zip [0..]
```

However, according to the implementation of `zip` in [`GHC.List` as of `base-4.9.1.0`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zip), this will not completely perform list fusion, i.e. this will not actually generate the list [0..], but the argument list to `indexify` will be constructed.

Of course, there is a definition that allows appropriate list fusion:

```
indexify' :: (Num i) => [a] -> [(i,a)]
indexify' xs = build $ \c n ->
                foldr (\x r !i -> (i,x) `c` r (i+1)) (const n) xs 0
```

Do we need to `import GHC.Prim (build)` to do this? Or is there another implementation that simplifies to `indexify'`?

Comment: Would `indexify = let f !i x = (i + 1, (i, x)) in snd . mapAccumL f 0` work? I believe `mapAccumL` is subject to fusion.

Comment: @Alec I was about to turn your comment into an answer and accept it, but it doesn't work. `mapAccumL` is defined in term of `traverse = mapM`, and it fuses in "consumption" direction (i.e. it uses `foldr`), but it doesn't fuse in "production" direction (i.e. it doesn't use `build`).

Comment: Ah. Good point. Should've thought about that. Still slightly better than `zip`. :)

Comment: Yes, it's something to be pointed out: it's better than `zip`. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if `mapAccumL` could be made to fuse in both directions. David Feuer is the expert on that.

Comment: Also see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9495 for some background.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.17/ilist-0.2.0.0/Data-List-Index.html#v:indexed) should more or less answer your question. TL;DR: there doesn't seem to be a simpler implementation, you can import `build` from `GHC.Exts`.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner My feeling is... "If we were happy to throw away the final accumlated value, we could do the trick." For the background, it is the first time to see the talk page (though I've read the background in the code). Thank you for reference.

Comment: @Alec Oh, it's done already. Thank you for pointing out. Would you like to make it an answer yourself? If not, shall I do it for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This already exists in the [`ilist`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.17/package/ilist-0.2.0.0) package, as [`indexed`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.17/ilist-0.2.0.0/Data-List-Index.html#v:indexed). The relevant source code snippets are

```
import GHC.Exts  -- exports `build`

indexed :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
indexed xs = go 0# xs
  where
    go i (a:as) = (I# i, a) : go (i +# 1#) as
    go _ _ = []
{-# NOINLINE [1] indexed #-}

indexedFB :: ((Int, a) -> t -> t) -> a -> (Int# -> t) -> Int# -> t
indexedFB c = \x cont i -> (I# i, x) `c` cont (i +# 1#)
{-# INLINE [0] indexedFB #-}

{-# RULES
"indexed"       [~1] forall xs.    indexed xs = build (\c n -> foldr (indexedFB c) (\_ -> n) xs 0#)
"indexedList"   [1]  forall xs.    foldr (indexedFB (:)) (\_ -> []) xs 0# = indexed xs
  #-}
```

As you'll probably notice, the rewrite rule makes use of pretty much the same definition you have, so that probably is the best way to do it. Also, `GHC.Exts` also exports `build`, so you don't need to import `GHC.Prim`.

Answer (score 0):

["Shortcut Fusion for Accumulating Parameters & Zip-like Functions](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Ejosefs/publications/fusion.pdf)

It shows `zip` fusion. In short, for `zip`-like functions the dual, `unfoldr/destroy`, is to be used.